# How to initialize USBFS to Device mode in Sipeed Longan Nano (GD32VF103CBT6)

Tags: c, embedded, usb, microcontroller

I want to have my Sipeed Longan Nano work as USB device.

To begin with, I want it to receive the "get device descriptor" request from the host.

(The goal of this question is to see something put to the RX FIFO. Reading what is put will be my next topic to learn and is out-of-scope of this question.)

I thought I wrote enough code to initialize the USBFS peripheral, but it doesn't seem receiving anything from the host.

I checked resistance values from the PA11 (D-) and PA12 (D+) pins to VDD and GND. The result is:

| pin | to VDD | to GND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PA11 (D-) | over 2000k ohm | about 10k ohm |
| PA12 (D+) | over 2000k ohm | about 10k ohm |

When I set the device to programming mode (it looks recognized as "unknown device" in Windows device manager), the values are:

| pin | to VDD | to GND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PA11 (D-) | over 2000k ohm | about 10k ohm |
| PA12 (D+) | about 15k ohm | over 2000k ohm |

The result differs, so it looks suggesting that the USBFS is not working with my configuration.

How should I initialize the USBFS peripheral to have the device work as USB Device and receive requests from the host?

Here is a part of my code that is initializing USBFS peripheral:

```c
void initializeUSB(void) {
    /* USBFS_GCCFG: ignore VBUS pin, PHY power on */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0038) |= (1 << 21) | (1 << 16);
    /* USBFS_GUSBCS: force device mode */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x000C) |= 1 << 30;
    /* USBFS_GINTF: wait until switched to device mode */
    while (PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0014) & 1);
    /* USBFS_GRFLEN: RX buffer size = 240 words */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0024) = 240;
    /* USBFS_HNPTFLEN _DIEP0TFLEN: TX buffer 0 size = 20 words */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0028) = (20 << 16) | 240;
    /* USBFS_GINTEN */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0018) =
        (1 << 19) | /* OUT endpoints interrupt enable */
        (1 << 18) | /* IN endpoints interrupt enable */
        (1 << 13) | /* Enumeration finish interrupt enable */
        (1 << 12) | /* USB reset interrupt enable */
        (1 << 4); /* Receive FIFO non-empty interrupt enable */
    /* USBFS_GAHBCS: enable global interrupt */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0008) = 1;
    /* USBFS_DCFG */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0800) = 3; /* Full speed */

    /* USBFS_GRSTCTL: reset TX and RX FIFO */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0010) = (0x10 << 6) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 4);
    /* wait for FIFO reset */
    while (PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0010) & ((1 << 5) | (1 << 4)));

    /* IN (device -> host) endpoint 0 */
    /* USBFS_DIEP0CTL: active, maximum packet length = 64 bytes */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0900) = (1 << 15) | 0;

    /* OUT (host -> device) endpoint 0 */
    /* USBFS_DOEP0LEN: SETUP packet count = 3, packet count = 1, transfer length = 64 */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0B10) = (3 << 29) | (1 << 19) | 64;
    /* USBFS_DOEP0CTL: enable, active */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0B00) = (1u << 31) | (1 << 15);

    /* USBFS_DCTL: power-on initialization finished */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0804) = 1 << 11;
}
```

---

Full code (marked up as JavaScript while they are not because I couldn't find better ways to have it hide my code not to make the question look too long)

`risu.txt`

```js
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littleriscv)
ENTRY(_start)

MEMORY {
    FLASH (xr): ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 128K
    SRAM (xw): ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 32K
}

PHDRS {
    text PT_LOAD FLAGS (6 /* SHF_ALLOC | SHF_EXECINSTR */);
    data PT_LOAD FLAGS (7 /* SHF_WRITE | SHF_ALLOC | SHF_EXECINSTR */);
}

SECTIONS {
    .startup : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.startup));
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } > FLASH :text

    .text : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.text)
        *(.text*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } > FLASH :text

    .rodata : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.rodata)
        *(.rodata*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } > FLASH :text

    .data : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _init_data_dest_start = .;
        *(.data)
        *(.data*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.sdata)
        *(.sdata*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _init_data_dest_end = .;
    } > SRAM AT > FLASH :data
    _init_data_src_start = . + LOADADDR(.data) - ADDR(.data);

    .bss : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _bss_start = .;
        *(.bss)
        *(.bss*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.sbss)
        *(.sbss*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _bss_end = .;
    } > SRAM :data
}
```

`startup.s`

```js
.extern _init_data_src_start
.extern _init_data_dest_start
.extern _init_data_dest_end
.extern _bss_start
.extern _bss_end

.section .startup, "ax"
.global _start
_start:
    .option push
    .option norvc
    lui a5, %hi(start_code)
    addi a5, a5, %lo(start_code)
    jalr zero, a5
    .option pop

interrupt_vector_table:
    .long _interrupt_handler_clic_sft
    .long _interrupt_handler_4
    .long _interrupt_handler_5
    .long _interrupt_handler_6
    .long _interrupt_handler_clic_tmr
    .long _interrupt_handler_8
    .long _interrupt_handler_9
    .long _interrupt_handler_10
    .long _interrupt_handler_11
    .long _interrupt_handler_12
    .long _interrupt_handler_13
    .long _interrupt_handler_14
    .long _interrupt_handler_15
    .long _interrupt_handler_16
    .long _interrupt_handler_clic_bwei
    .long _interrupt_handler_clic_pmovi
    .long _interrupt_handler_wwdgt
    .long _interrupt_handler_lvd # 20
    .long _interrupt_handler_tamper
    .long _interrupt_handler_rtc
    .long _interrupt_handler_fmc
    .long _interrupt_handler_rcu
    .long _interrupt_handler_exti_0
    .long _interrupt_handler_exti_1
    .long _interrupt_handler_exti_2
    .long _interrupt_handler_exti_3
    .long _interrupt_handler_exti_4
    .long _interrupt_handler_dma0_0 # 30
    .long _interrupt_handler_dma0_1
    .long _interrupt_handler_dma0_2
    .long _interrupt_handler_dma0_3
    .long _interrupt_handler_dma0_4
    .long _interrupt_handler_dma0_5
    .long _interrupt_handler_dma0_6
    .long _interrupt_handler_adc
    .long _interrupt_handler_can0_tx
    .long _interrupt_handler_can0_rx0
    .long _interrupt_handler_can0_rx1 # 40
    .long _interrupt_handler_can0_ewmc
    .long _interrupt_handler_exti_5_9
    .long _interrupt_handler_timer0_break
    .long _interrupt_handler_timer0_update
    .long _interrupt_handler_timer0_trigger
    .long _interrupt_handler_timer0_compare
    .long _interrupt_handler_timer1
    .long _interrupt_handler_timer2
    .long _interrupt_handler_timer3
    .long _interrupt_handler_i2c0_event # 50
    .long _interrupt_handler_i2c0_error
    .long _interrupt_handler_i2c1_event
    .long _interrupt_handler_i2c1_error
    .long _interrupt_handler_spi0
    .long _interrupt_handler_spi1
    .long _interrupt_handler_usart0
    .long _interrupt_handler_usart1
    .long _interrupt_handler_usart2
    .long _interrupt_handler_exti_10_15
    .long _interrupt_handler_rtc_alarm # 60
    .long _interrupt_handler_usbfs_wakeup
    .long _interrupt_handler_62
    .long _interrupt_handler_63
    .long _interrupt_handler_64
    .long _interrupt_handler_65
    .long _interrupt_handler_66
    .long _interrupt_handler_67
    .long _interrupt_handler_68
    .long _interrupt_handler_timer4
    .long _interrupt_handler_spi2 # 70
    .long _interrupt_handler_uart3
    .long _interrupt_handler_uart4
    .long _interrupt_handler_timer5
    .long _interrupt_handler_timer6
    .long _interrupt_handler_dma1_0
    .long _interrupt_handler_dma1_1
    .long _interrupt_handler_dma1_2
    .long _interrupt_handler_dma1_3
    .long _interrupt_handler_dma1_4
    .long _interrupt_handler_80 # 80
    .long _interrupt_handler_81
    .long _interrupt_handler_can1_tx
    .long _interrupt_handler_can1_rx0
    .long _interrupt_handler_can1_rx1
    .long _interrupt_handler_can1_ewmc
    .long _interrupt_handler_usbfs # 86
interrupt_vector_table_end:

# "do nothing"
.weak main
.weak _interrupt_handler_clic_sft
.weak _interrupt_handler_4
.weak _interrupt_handler_5
.weak _interrupt_handler_6
.weak _interrupt_handler_clic_tmr
.weak _interrupt_handler_8
.weak _interrupt_handler_9
.weak _interrupt_handler_10
.weak _interrupt_handler_11
.weak _interrupt_handler_12
.weak _interrupt_handler_13
.weak _interrupt_handler_14
.weak _interrupt_handler_15
.weak _interrupt_handler_16
.weak _interrupt_handler_clic_bwei
.weak _interrupt_handler_clic_pmovi
.weak _interrupt_handler_wwdgt
.weak _interrupt_handler_lvd
.weak _interrupt_handler_tamper
.weak _interrupt_handler_rtc
.weak _interrupt_handler_fmc
.weak _interrupt_handler_rcu
.weak _interrupt_handler_exti_0
.weak _interrupt_handler_exti_1
.weak _interrupt_handler_exti_2
.weak _interrupt_handler_exti_3
.weak _interrupt_handler_exti_4
.weak _interrupt_handler_dma0_0
.weak _interrupt_handler_dma0_1
.weak _interrupt_handler_dma0_2
.weak _interrupt_handler_dma0_3
.weak _interrupt_handler_dma0_4
.weak _interrupt_handler_dma0_5
.weak _interrupt_handler_dma0_6
.weak _interrupt_handler_adc
.weak _interrupt_handler_can0_tx
.weak _interrupt_handler_can0_rx0
.weak _interrupt_handler_can0_rx1
.weak _interrupt_handler_can0_ewmc
.weak _interrupt_handler_exti_5_9
.weak _interrupt_handler_timer0_break
.weak _interrupt_handler_timer0_update
.weak _interrupt_handler_timer0_trigger
.weak _interrupt_handler_timer0_compare
.weak _interrupt_handler_timer1
.weak _interrupt_handler_timer2
.weak _interrupt_handler_timer3
.weak _interrupt_handler_i2c0_event
.weak _interrupt_handler_i2c0_error
.weak _interrupt_handler_i2c1_event
.weak _interrupt_handler_i2c1_error
.weak _interrupt_handler_spi0
.weak _interrupt_handler_spi1
.weak _interrupt_handler_usart0
.weak _interrupt_handler_usart1
.weak _interrupt_handler_usart2
.weak _interrupt_handler_exti_10_15
.weak _interrupt_handler_rtc_alarm
.weak _interrupt_handler_usbfs_wakeup
.weak _interrupt_handler_62
.weak _interrupt_handler_63
.weak _interrupt_handler_64
.weak _interrupt_handler_65
.weak _interrupt_handler_66
.weak _interrupt_handler_67
.weak _interrupt_handler_68
.weak _interrupt_handler_timer4
.weak _interrupt_handler_spi2
.weak _interrupt_handler_uart3
.weak _interrupt_handler_uart4
.weak _interrupt_handler_timer5
.weak _interrupt_handler_timer6
.weak _interrupt_handler_dma1_0
.weak _interrupt_handler_dma1_1
.weak _interrupt_handler_dma1_2
.weak _interrupt_handler_dma1_3
.weak _interrupt_handler_dma1_4
.weak _interrupt_handler_80
.weak _interrupt_handler_81
.weak _interrupt_handler_can1_tx
.weak _interrupt_handler_can1_rx0
.weak _interrupt_handler_can1_rx1
.weak _interrupt_handler_can1_ewmc
.weak _interrupt_handler_usbfs
main:
_interrupt_handler_clic_sft:
_interrupt_handler_4:
_interrupt_handler_5:
_interrupt_handler_6:
_interrupt_handler_clic_tmr:
_interrupt_handler_8:
_interrupt_handler_9:
_interrupt_handler_10:
_interrupt_handler_11:
_interrupt_handler_12:
_interrupt_handler_13:
_interrupt_handler_14:
_interrupt_handler_15:
_interrupt_handler_16:
_interrupt_handler_clic_bwei:
_interrupt_handler_clic_pmovi:
_interrupt_handler_wwdgt:
_interrupt_handler_lvd:
_interrupt_handler_tamper:
_interrupt_handler_rtc:
_interrupt_handler_fmc:
_interrupt_handler_rcu:
_interrupt_handler_exti_0:
_interrupt_handler_exti_1:
_interrupt_handler_exti_2:
_interrupt_handler_exti_3:
_interrupt_handler_exti_4:
_interrupt_handler_dma0_0:
_interrupt_handler_dma0_1:
_interrupt_handler_dma0_2:
_interrupt_handler_dma0_3:
_interrupt_handler_dma0_4:
_interrupt_handler_dma0_5:
_interrupt_handler_dma0_6:
_interrupt_handler_adc:
_interrupt_handler_can0_tx:
_interrupt_handler_can0_rx0:
_interrupt_handler_can0_rx1:
_interrupt_handler_can0_ewmc:
_interrupt_handler_exti_5_9:
_interrupt_handler_timer0_break:
_interrupt_handler_timer0_update:
_interrupt_handler_timer0_trigger:
_interrupt_handler_timer0_compare:
_interrupt_handler_timer1:
_interrupt_handler_timer2:
_interrupt_handler_timer3:
_interrupt_handler_i2c0_event:
_interrupt_handler_i2c0_error:
_interrupt_handler_i2c1_event:
_interrupt_handler_i2c1_error:
_interrupt_handler_spi0:
_interrupt_handler_spi1:
_interrupt_handler_usart0:
_interrupt_handler_usart1:
_interrupt_handler_usart2:
_interrupt_handler_exti_10_15:
_interrupt_handler_rtc_alarm:
_interrupt_handler_usbfs_wakeup:
_interrupt_handler_62:
_interrupt_handler_63:
_interrupt_handler_64:
_interrupt_handler_65:
_interrupt_handler_66:
_interrupt_handler_67:
_interrupt_handler_68:
_interrupt_handler_timer4:
_interrupt_handler_spi2:
_interrupt_handler_uart3:
_interrupt_handler_uart4:
_interrupt_handler_timer5:
_interrupt_handler_timer6:
_interrupt_handler_dma1_0:
_interrupt_handler_dma1_1:
_interrupt_handler_dma1_2:
_interrupt_handler_dma1_3:
_interrupt_handler_dma1_4:
_interrupt_handler_80:
_interrupt_handler_81:
_interrupt_handler_can1_tx:
_interrupt_handler_can1_rx0:
_interrupt_handler_can1_rx1:
_interrupt_handler_can1_ewmc:
_interrupt_handler_usbfs:
null_interrupt_handler:
    ret

.p2align 2
interrupt_handler_common:
    # save caller-save registers
    addi sp, sp, -80
    sw ra, 0(sp)
    sw t0, 4(sp)
    sw t1, 8(sp)
    sw t2, 12(sp)
    sw a0, 16(sp)
    sw a1, 20(sp)
    sw a2, 24(sp)
    sw a3, 28(sp)
    sw a4, 32(sp)
    sw a5, 36(sp)
    sw a6, 40(sp)
    sw a7, 44(sp)
    sw t3, 48(sp)
    sw t4, 52(sp)
    sw t5, 56(sp)
    sw t6, 60(sp)
    # save mepc, mcause, msubm
    csrrci a0, 0x341, 0
    sw a0, 64(sp)
    csrrci a0, 0x342, 0
    sw a0, 68(sp)
    csrrci a0, 0x7c4, 0
    sw a0, 72(sp)
    # call interrupt handler (CSR_JALMNXTI)
    csrrw ra, 0x7ed, ra
    # disable interrupts
    csrrci zero, 0x300, 0x8
    # restore mepc, mcause, msubm
    lw a0, 64(sp)
    csrrw zero, 0x341, a0
    lw a0, 68(sp)
    csrrw zero, 0x342, a0
    lw a0, 72(sp)
    csrrw zero, 0x7c4, a0
    # restor caller-save registers
    lw ra, 0(sp)
    lw t0, 4(sp)
    lw t1, 8(sp)
    lw t2, 12(sp)
    lw a0, 16(sp)
    lw a1, 20(sp)
    lw a2, 24(sp)
    lw a3, 28(sp)
    lw a4, 32(sp)
    lw a5, 36(sp)
    lw a6, 40(sp)
    lw a7, 44(sp)
    lw t3, 48(sp)
    lw t4, 52(sp)
    lw t5, 56(sp)
    lw t6, 60(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 80
    mret

start_code:
    # initialize stack pointer to the end of SRAM
    lui a5, %hi(0x1ffff7e0)
    lw a4, %lo(0x1ffff7e0)(a5)
    srli a4, a4, 16
    slli a4, a4, 10
    lui a3, 0x20000
    add sp, a4, a3

    # copy initialization data for .data
    lui a5, %hi(_init_data_dest_start)
    addi a5, a5, %lo(_init_data_dest_start)
    lui a4, %hi(_init_data_dest_start)
    addi a4, a4, %lo(_init_data_dest_start)
    lui a3, %hi(_init_data_src_start)
    addi a3, a3, %lo(_init_data_src_start)
    j copy_initialization_data_initial
copy_initialization_data:
    lw a2, (a3)
    sw a2, (a4)
    addi a3, a3, 4
    addi a4, a4, 4
copy_initialization_data_initial:
    bltu a4, a5, copy_initialization_data

    # initialize .bss to zero
    lui a5, %hi(_bss_end)
    addi a5, a5, %lo(_bss_end)
    lui a4, %hi(_bss_start)
    addi a4, a4, %lo(_bss_start)
    j initialize_bss_initial
initialize_bss:
    sw zero, (a4)
    addi a4, a4, 4
initialize_bss_initial:
    bltu a4, a5, initialize_bss

    # initialize interrupt handler
    csrrwi zero, 0x305, 3 # set mtvec = 3 (ECLIC Interrupt Mode)
    csrrwi zero, 0x307, 0 # set mtvt (interrupt vector) = 0
    lui a5, %hi(interrupt_handler_common)
    addi a5, a5, %lo(interrupt_handler_common)
    ori a5, a5, 1
    csrrw zero, 0x7ec, a5 # enable mtvt2 and set common interrupt handler
    lui a5, 0xd2000 # ECLIC registers base
    li a4, 1
    sb a4, (a5) # cliccfg.nlbits = 0
    sb zero, 0xb(a5) # mth = 0
    li a5, 0xd200100c
    lui a4, %hi(interrupt_vector_table)
    addi a4, a4, %lo(interrupt_vector_table)
    lui a3, %hi(interrupt_vector_table_end)
    addi a3, a3, %lo(interrupt_vector_table_end)
    lui a2, %hi(null_interrupt_handler)
    addi a2, a2, %lo(null_interrupt_handler)
initialize_interrupt_handler:
    li a0, 0xc0
    sb a0, 2(a5) # non-vectored, level triggered
    sb zero, 3(a5) # lowest level and priority
    li a0, 0
    lw a1, (a4)
    beq a1, a2, initialize_interrupt_handler_skip_enable
    li a0, 1
initialize_interrupt_handler_skip_enable:
    sb a0, 1(a5) # enable interrupt iff interrupt handler is set to non-default
    addi a5, a5, 4
    addi a4, a4, 4
    bltu a4, a3, initialize_interrupt_handler

    # execute main code
    call main

    # stop
end_loop:
    j end_loop
```

`usbtest.c`

```js
#define PORT8(addr) (*(volatile unsigned char*)(addr))
#define PORT16(addr) (*(volatile unsigned short*)(addr))
#define PORT32(addr) (*(volatile unsigned int*)(addr))
#define CLI() __asm__ __volatile__("csrrci zero, 0x300, 0x8")
#define STI() __asm__ __volatile__("csrrsi zero, 0x300, 0x8")

/*
PREDV0 input = HXTAL
PREDV0 = /1
PLL input = PREDV0
PLL = x12 (8MHz -> 96MHz)
CK_SYS = CK_PLL
USB prescaler = /2 (96MHz -> 48MHz)
AHB prescaler = /1
APB1 prescaler = /16 (96MHz -> 6MHz, TIMER1-6: 12MHz)
APB2 prescaler = /16 (96MHz -> 6MHz)
ADC prescaler = /2 (6MHz -> 3MHz)
*/
void initializeClock(void) {
    /* set RCU_CFG0 */
    PORT32(0x40021000 + 0x04) =
        (0 << 24) | /* CKOUT0 Clock Source = None */
        (3 << 22) | /* USBFS clock prescaler = /2 */
        (0 << 29) | (0xA << 18) | /* PLL = x12 */
        (0 << 17) | /* PREDV0 = /1 */
        (1 << 16) | /* PLL input = HXTAL */
        (0 << 28) | (0 << 14) | /* ADC prescaler = /2 */
        (7 << 11) | /* APB2 prescaler = /16 */
        (7 << 8) | /* APB1 prescaler = /16 */
        (0 << 4) | /* AHB prescaler = /1 */
        0; /* CK_SYS = CK_IRC8M */
    /* enable PLL and HXTAL */
    PORT32(0x40021000 + 0x00) |= (1 << 24) | (1 << 16);
    /* wait until PLL and HXTAL stable */
    while (~PORT32(0x40021000 + 0x00) & ((1 << 25) | (1 << 17)));
    /* set CK_SYS = CK_PLL */
    PORT32(0x40021000 + 0x04) |= 2;
    /* wait until CK_PLL is selected */
    while ((PORT32(0x40021000 + 0x04) & 0xC) != 0x8);
    /* disable IRC8M */
    PORT32(0x40021000 + 0x00) &= ~1;

    /* enable USBFS and DMA0 clock */
    PORT32(0x40021000 + 0x14) |= (1 << 12) | (1 << 0);
    /* enable USART0 and PORTA clock */
    PORT32(0x40021000 + 0x18) |= (1 << 14) | (1 << 2);
}

/*
PA12 (USBFS_DP) : AFIO output, 50MHz, push-pull
PA11 (USBFS_DM) : AFIO output, 50MHz, push-pull
PA10 (UART0 RX) : input, weak pull-up
PA9  (UART0 TX) : AFIO output, 10MHz, push-pull
*/
void initializePort(void) {
    /* set GPIOA_CTL1 */
    PORT32(0x40010800 + 0x04) = (PORT32(0x40010800 + 0x04) & 0xfff0000f) | 0xBB890;
    /* set PA10 to HIGH (pull-up) via GPIOA_BOP */
    PORT32(0x40010800 + 0x10) = 1 << 10;
}

volatile unsigned char uart_tx_qs, uart_tx_qe;
volatile short uart_tx_dma_len;
unsigned char uart_tx_q[256];
volatile unsigned char uart_rx_qs, uart_rx_qe;
unsigned char uart_rx_q[256];

/*
UART0: 8 data bits, no pality, 9600bps
*/
void initializeUart(void) {
    /* USART_CTL0: enable RX interrupt, enable transmitter, enable receiver */
    PORT32(0x40013800 + 0x0C) = (1 << 5) | (1 << 3) | (1 << 2);
    /* USART_CTL2: enable transmission DMA request */
    PORT32(0x40013800 + 0x14) = 1 << 7;
    /* USART_BAUD */
    PORT32(0x40013800 + 0x08) = 6000000 / 9600;

    /* initialize DMA0 Channel 3 (USART0_TX) */
    /* DMA_CH3CTL */
    PORT32(0x40020000 + 0x08 + 0x14 * 3) =
        (2 << 8) | /* 32-bit access for peripheral */
        (1 << 7) | /* increase memory address */
        (1 << 4) | /* memory to peripheral */
        (1 << 1); /* enable full transfer finish interrupt */
    /* DMA_CH3PADDR = USART_DATA */
    PORT32(0x40020000 + 0x10 + 0x14 * 3) = 0x40013800 + 0x04;

    /* initialize variables */
    uart_tx_qs = 0;
    uart_tx_qe = 0;
    uart_tx_dma_len = 0;
    uart_rx_qs = 0;
    uart_rx_qe = 0;

    /* USART_CTL0: enable UART0 */
    PORT32(0x40013800 + 0x0C) |= 1 << 13;
}

void start_uart_tx_dma(void) {
    /* disable Channel 3 */
    PORT32(0x40020000 + 0x08 + 0x14 * 3) &= ~1;
    /* check if data exists in the queue */
    if (uart_tx_qs != uart_tx_qe) {
        int queue_data_end = uart_tx_qe < uart_tx_qs ? 256 : uart_tx_qe;
        uart_tx_dma_len = queue_data_end - uart_tx_qs;
        /* DMA_CH3MADDR */
        PORT32(0x40020000 + 0x14 + 0x14 * 3) = (unsigned int)uart_tx_q + uart_tx_qs;
        /* DMA_CH3CNT */
        PORT32(0x40020000 + 0x0C + 0x14 * 3) = uart_tx_dma_len;
        /* enable Channel 3 */
        PORT32(0x40020000 + 0x08 + 0x14 * 3) |= 1;
    } else {
        uart_tx_dma_len = 0;
    }
}

void _interrupt_handler_dma0_3(void) {
    /* check for Channel 3 full transfer finish flag */
    if (!(PORT32(0x40020000 + 0x00) & (1 << 13))) return;
    /* clear for Channel 3 flags */
    PORT32(0x40020000 + 0x04) = 1 << 12;
    /* dequeue data sent */
    uart_tx_qs += uart_tx_dma_len;
    /* start next transmission */
    start_uart_tx_dma();
}

void _interrupt_handler_usart0(void) {
    unsigned int status, data;
    status = PORT32(0x40013800 + 0x00);
    if (!(status & 0x2f)) return; /* check for received data or error */
    data = PORT32(0x40013800 + 0x04);
    /* check if data is received and no error is detected */
    if ((status & (1 << 5)) && !(status & 7)) {
        /* put received data if the buffer has a room */
        unsigned char uart_rx_qe_next = uart_rx_qe + 1; /* convert to unsigned char for wraparound */
        if (uart_rx_qe_next != uart_rx_qs) {
            uart_rx_q[uart_rx_qe] = data;
            uart_rx_qe = uart_rx_qe_next;
        }
    }
}

int uart_getchar(void) {
    int ret;
    while (uart_rx_qs == uart_rx_qe);
    ret = uart_rx_q[uart_rx_qs];
    uart_rx_qs++;
    return ret;
}

void uart_putchar(int c) {
    while ((unsigned char)(uart_tx_qe + 1) == uart_tx_qs);
    uart_tx_q[uart_tx_qe] = c;
    uart_tx_qe++;
    if (uart_tx_dma_len == 0) start_uart_tx_dma();
}

void uart_print_string(const char* str) {
    while (*str) uart_putchar(*(str++));
}

void uart_puts(const char* str) {
    uart_print_string(str);
    uart_putchar('\n');
}

void uart_print_number(unsigned int value, unsigned int radix, int least_digits) {
    unsigned int value2 = value;
    char buffer[340], *ptr = buffer;
    do {
        *(ptr++) = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[value2 % radix];
        value2 /= radix;
        if (least_digits > 0) least_digits--;
    } while (value2 > 0 || least_digits);
    do {
        uart_putchar(*(--ptr));
    } while (ptr != buffer);
}

void initializeUSB(void) {
    /* USBFS_GCCFG: ignore VBUS pin, PHY power on */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0038) |= (1 << 21) | (1 << 16);
    /* USBFS_GUSBCS: force device mode */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x000C) |= 1 << 30;
    /* USBFS_GINTF: wait until switched to device mode */
    while (PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0014) & 1);
    /* USBFS_GRFLEN: RX buffer size = 240 words */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0024) = 240;
    /* USBFS_HNPTFLEN _DIEP0TFLEN: TX buffer 0 size = 20 words */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0028) = (20 << 16) | 240;
    /* USBFS_GINTEN */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0018) =
        (1 << 19) | /* OUT endpoints interrupt enable */
        (1 << 18) | /* IN endpoints interrupt enable */
        (1 << 13) | /* Enumeration finish interrupt enable */
        (1 << 12) | /* USB reset interrupt enable */
        (1 << 4); /* Receive FIFO non-empty interrupt enable */
    /* USBFS_GAHBCS: enable global interrupt */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0008) = 1;
    /* USBFS_DCFG */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0800) = 3; /* Full speed */

    /* USBFS_GRSTCTL: reset TX and RX FIFO */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0010) = (0x10 << 6) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 4);
    /* wait for FIFO reset */
    while (PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0010) & ((1 << 5) | (1 << 4)));

    /* IN (device -> host) endpoint 0 */
    /* USBFS_DIEP0CTL: active, maximum packet length = 64 bytes */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0900) = (1 << 15) | 0;

    /* OUT (host -> device) endpoint 0 */
    /* USBFS_DOEP0LEN: SETUP packet count = 3, packet count = 1, transfer length = 64 */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0B10) = (3 << 29) | (1 << 19) | 64;
    /* USBFS_DOEP0CTL: enable, active */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0B00) = (1u << 31) | (1 << 15);

    /* USBFS_DCTL: power-on initialization finished */
    PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0804) = 1 << 11;
}

void _interrupt_handler_usbfs(void) {
    /* USBFS_GINTF */
    unsigned int flags = PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0014);
    if ((flags >> 12) & 1) {
        /* USB reset */
        PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0014) = 1 << 12;
        uart_puts("USB reset");
    }
    if ((flags >> 13) & 1) {
        /* Enumeration finished */
        PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0014) = 1 << 13;
        uart_puts("Enumeration finished");
    }
    if ((flags >> 4) & 1) {
        /* Rx FIFO non-empty */
        /* USBFS_GRSTATR */
        unsigned int status = PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x001C);

        uart_print_string("RX status = 0x");
        uart_print_number(status, 16, 8);
        uart_putchar('\n');

        /* USBFS_GRSTATP (pop receive status) */
        status = PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0020);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    initializeClock();
    initializePort();
    initializeUart();
    initializeUSB();
    STI();

    uart_puts("hello, world!");

    for(;;) {
        int c = uart_getchar();
        /* uart_putchar(c + 1); */
        if (c == 'D') {
            uart_puts("set soft disconnect");
            PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0804) |= 2;
        } else if (c == 'd') {
            uart_puts("clear soft disconnect");
            PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0804) &= ~2;
        }
        uart_print_number(PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0014), 16, 8);
        uart_putchar(' ');
        uart_print_number(PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0808), 16, 8);
        uart_putchar(' ');
        uart_print_number(PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0B08), 16, 8);
        uart_putchar(' ');
        uart_print_number(PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0804), 16, 8);
        uart_print_string(" | ");
        uart_print_number(PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0B00), 16, 8);
        uart_putchar(' ');
        uart_print_number(PORT32(0x50000000 + 0x0B10), 16, 8);
        uart_putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

To build, put above files to [JSLinux](https://bellard.org/jslinux/vm.html?cpu=riscv64&url=fedora33-riscv.cfg&mem=256) and execute these commands:

```
gcc -c -march=rv32imc -mabi=ilp32 -O2 startup.s
gcc -c -march=rv32imc -mabi=ilp32 -O2 -Wall -Wextra usbtest.c
ld -T risu.txt -o usbtest.elf startup.o usbtest.o
objcopy -O binary usbtest.elf usbtest.bin
```

You'll get the file `usbtest.bin`, which should be programmed into the device.

After being programmed, it uses USART0 (TX on PA9, RX on PA10, 9600bps, no parity bit) to tell its status and accept some commands.

Commands:

- `D` (large D): set soft disconnect bit and show some register values
- `d` (small D): clear soft disconnect bit and show some register values
- the other characters: show some register values

Compiler version:

```
[root@localhost ~]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 10.2.1 20201125 (Red Hat 10.2.1-9)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 
[root@localhost ~]# ld --version
GNU ld version 2.35-15.fc33
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
[root@localhost ~]# objcopy --version
GNU objcopy version 2.35-15.fc33
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) any later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```